# Random background image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, background

here's my code:

```
function drawBgrImage() {

    var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
    var folder;
    var path;

    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        folder = "xs";
    } else if (window.innerWidth <= 1200) {
        folder = "sm";
    } else {
        folder = "lg";
    }

    path = '"url(/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/' + folder + '/' + random + '.jpg)"';
    console.log(path);
    document.getElementById("bgrImg").style.backgroundImage = path;
    /*document.getElementById("bgrImg").style.backgroundImage = "url(/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/lg/2.jpg)";*/
}


window.onload = drawBgrImage();
```

In folders xs, sm and lg I have 9 .jpg files. Function .drawBgrImage() is to draw a number from 1 to 9 and set image background on specified #bgrImg. 
although var path returns the same value, as commented line it doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `onload` should be a function, however you don't provide one. It should be:

```
window.onload = drawBgrImage;
```

By putting parentheses after function name you invoke it immediately and assign `window.onload` return value (which is undefined in your case).

Another issue is that you wrapped path url into unnecessary quotes. Fix it like this:

```
path = 'url(/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/' + folder + '/' + random + '.jpg)';
```

Comment: I've tried window.onload = function() { drawBgrImage(); }; and window.onload = drawBgrImage; - it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
path = '"url(/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/' + folder + '/' + random + '.jpg)"';
```

with:

```
path = 'url(/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/' + folder + '/' + random + '.jpg)';
```